# Can "face pulling" or "bone pulling" really move/remodel bones in adults?

Tags: bones, face

Face pulling is a technique some people use to try and move their maxillas/cheekbones/etc. more forward. It's basically biting on some object and slowly and steadily pulling with tension forward and upwards for long periods of time. Basically the teeth are like an anchor and are obviously part of the maxilla bone, which is connected to zygoma/etc.

So basically, is there any reason to believe this can work (non-surgically)? That the bones will remodel or something and will actually give the desired results these people seek? I mean they have these reverse pull headgear devices and other stuff for children (dentistry, orthodontics, etc.). Is it theoretically possible this can work in adults too?

Or in other words, can constant, steady, mechanical tension/force make bones adapt/remodel to pressure and give desired results (i.e., more tautness in face/bone projection in, say, people with bone recession or not so ideal bone structure in their faces for various other reasons)? This is related to bone biology. It would be amazing if this could be elaborated on.

Many people suffer from recession/bad facial bone structure and orthodontics are out of a handful of people's budgets. These techniques -- if proven useful -- can dramatically change a person's appearance and confidence + life quality..

Comment: Can you link to a source that claims this is possible and how?

Comment: Considering that the OP deleted their account I don't think they'll be providing links.

Comment: Here's an example of this practice.  https://www.facepulling.com/